# Procedural normals make object look flat-shaded

Tags: normals

I came across an issue that now seems to be present in all my projects. Any normal maps using a procedural texture (such as noise, musgrave, or voronoi) look slightly flat, even on fully smooth-shaded objects. After looking at the normals themselves on an object, I found out that they don't connect at the edges, which seems to be what's causing the flat shading. I still don't know how to fix it however.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using Blender 2.93.2. Let me know if any other information is needed.

Comment: Turn the distance way down

Comment: Check in properties > vertices (green triangle) > normals > if Autosmooth option is on, maybe with an angle value which is too small.

Comment: @AllenSimpson That doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: @joshsanfelici Autosmooth is off. That's not the problem. The problem is the normal map itself, since the object looks completely smooth without it.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem and i cant find any apparent solution anywhere. But if you dont need the procedural texture to move, i found some way around it. I will create desired texture and make the model subdivided/beveled as needed to obtain more normals-i call it normals to pixel resolution(i dont have too apply any modifier) then i put it into color channel(normals/bump are empty,metallic must be 0) and bake it as uv map. Then you can use it as normal/bump map with resolution of subsfurf.
I know that this is not ideal. But its best what i could do with that.
If there is a must for movement, only thing you can do is tweak screen space reflections in eevee render properties, but you will propably loose light effects this way.